# d3 Select and modify g elements within svg elements

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble selecting and manipulating (i want to add click behavior to) a path in inline svg code I produced in Inkscape and then pasted into my html file.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="905.1372px" height="1100px" viewBox="0 300 721.464 889.561" enable-background="new 0 0 721.464 889.561"
 xml:space="preserve">


<g id="section3">
<path  id="section"
   d="m 433.125,729.14792 -0.17857,32.67857 32.32143,0.44643 15.89286,-0.44643    11.78571,-3.03572 -11.33928,-35.26785 -19.82143,5.625 z"/>
</g>
```

I've tried all sorts of way.. getelementbyid, d3.select("#id").. can anyone help?

Comment: Show what you've tried as actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting by ID:

```
d3.select("#section3")
```

Check this demo, clicking on your path (you'll have to scroll down to find it):

```js
d3.select("#section3").on("click", function(){
  console.log("hello");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" id="layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="905.1372px" height="1100px" viewBox="0 300 721.464 889.561" enable-background="new 0 0 721.464 889.561"
 xml:space="preserve">


<g id="section3">
<path  id="section"
   d="m 433.125,729.14792 -0.17857,32.67857 32.32143,0.44643 15.89286,-0.44643    11.78571,-3.03572 -11.33928,-35.26785 -19.82143,5.625 z"/>
</g>
```